# Excel formula Sum of squares with IF AND conditions - not working

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 columns,
A with the condition, B with the values from which I need a sum of squares;

I tried the formula:
if A = "John" AND B is a number, take a square of B and SUM ALL.

```
=SUMSQ(IF(AND(A:A="John",ISNUMBER(B:B)),B:B,0))
```

But the formula above does not work

the issue is with AND, if I use it without AND, single condition it works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula instead:
`=SUMSQ(IF(A:A="John",IF(ISNUMBER(B:B),B:B,0),0))`

This formula first checks if column A equals "John", and then checks if the corresponding value in column B is a number. If both conditions are met, it takes the square of the value in column B. Finally, it calculates the sum of squares of all the values that meet these conditions.

Comment: or just: `=SUMSQ(IF((A:A="John")*(ISNUMBER(B:B)),B:B,0))`